# Scaffold-dbcontext not generating HasDefaultValueSql anymore?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Since a few versions ago the Scaffold-dbcontext command doesn't seem to be generating .HasDefaultValueSql("...") fluid code anymore for database contexts.

I used to be able to still do it on my home pc, but now it seems I'm not able to anymore ever since I installed the core 3.0 (or perhaps 2.2) sdk?

I can't find any documentation about it anywhere and need to know how to enable .HasDefaultValueSql("...") scaffolding since I can't scaffold my database anymore without breaking all of our existing projects.

**Update:**
Apparently it doesn't scaffold correctly on Sql Server 2017 but it does on Sql Server 2012.

**Update:** It seems it only appears to be happening while scaffolding while using my employer's VPN... The scaffolding is correct after creating the tables on a local database and scaffolding that.

Comment: What do you need the default for?

Comment: @ErikEJ Default values for string columns, newsequentialid() for Guid keys, default values for status fields, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was scaffolding using a user account that only had datareader/writer rights.

Switching to a different user account with more permissions did the trick.

Comment: Thank you was still valid for EFCore 6.0

Comment: You also need to grant the user VIEW DEFINITION permission. It is possible to still get this issue and be able to write to the database.

Worked for dotnet ef version 6.0.6 on EF Core 6 on SQL Server 12.0.2